# Show hide based on div not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div id="tabs">
    <div id="nav">
      <p>Show Div 1:<input type="radio" name="tab" value="pkfrom" class="div1" /></p>
      <p>Show Div 2:<input type="radio" name="tab" value="pkfrom" class="div2" /></p>
    </div>

    <div id="div1" class="tab">
     <? echo form_open('email/send');?>

      <table width="100%">
      <tr><td>

Username:</td><td><? echo form_input('username', 'your username');?></td></tr>
<tr><td> Name:</td><td> <? echo form_input('Name', '');?></td></tr>
<tr><td> Address:</td><td> <? echo form_textarea('address', '');?></td></tr>
<tr><td> Degree:</td><td> <? echo form_input('specialist', '');?></td></tr>
<tr><td> Degree:</td><td> <? echo form_input('specialist', '');?></td></tr>

<? echo form_close();?>
      </table>

    </div>

    <div id="div2" class="tab">
      <p>this is div 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    (function(){
      var tabs =document.getElementById('tabs');
      var nav = tabs.getElementsByTagName('input');

      /* 
      * Hide all tabs
      */
      function hideTabs(){
        var tab = tabs.getElementsByTagName('div');
        for(var i=0;i<=nav.length;i++){
          if(tab[i].className == 'tab'){
            tab[i].className = tab[i].className + ' hide';
          }
        }
      }

      /*
      * Show the clicked tab
      */
      function showTab(tab){
        document.getElementById(tab).className = 'tab'
      }

      hideTabs(); /* hide tabs on load */

      /* 
      * Add click events
      */
      for(var i=0;i<nav.length;i++){
        nav[i].onclick = function(){
          hideTabs();
          showTab(this.className);
        }
      }
    })();
  </script>
</div>
```

This is the coding for showing and hiding based on div. But it only works if i just type normal text in the divs. But if i add php or any html element it doesn't work.

Any idea how to correct it.

Thanks

Comment: Check you broncode, do have mabye two times a body tag or something. Because it doens't matter or you have text from php or you type the text

Comment: Any errors in the console? How does the generated HTML look like?

Answer (score 0):

I modified it a little and it seems to work for me:
I modified the following -

```
      if(tab[i].className == 'tab'){
       document.getElementById('div' + i).style.display = 'none';
      }
```

and

```
  function showTab(tab){
    document.getElementById(tab).style.display = 'block';
  }
```